How to test Spring Cloud Stream app without Message Broker when consuming and publishing from/to the same destination?
I have managed to setup Spring Cloud Stream/Function to consume and publish from/to the same destination:
application.yml:
    spring:
      cloud:
        stream:
          function:
            routing:
              enabled: true
          bindings:
            functionRouter-in-0:
              destination: order
              group: org.example.orderprocessing
            functionRouter-out-0:
              destination: order
              content-type: application/json;type=org.example.order.OrderCreatedEvent

Configuration:
    @Configuration
    public class Config {
        @Bean
        public Function<OrderSubmittedEvent, OrderCreatedEvent> orderSubmittedEventHandler() {
            return orderSubmittedEvent -> {
                log.info("Received OrderSubmittedEvent: {}", orderSubmittedEvent);
                return new OrderCreatedEvent(UUID.randomUUID(), orderSubmittedEvent.customerId(), orderSubmittedEvent.lineItems());
            };
        }
    
        @Bean
        public Consumer<OrderCreatedEvent> orderCreatedEventHandler() {
            return orderCreatedEvent -> {
                log.info("Received OrderCreatedEvent: {}", orderCreatedEvent);
            };
        }
    
        @Bean
        public Consumer<?> devNull() {
            return _ -> log.info("Received unknown message");
        }
    
        @Bean
        public MessageRoutingCallback typeMessageRoutingCallback() {
         return new MessageRoutingCallback() {
                @Override
                public String routingResult(Message<?> message) {
                    return Optional.of(message.getHeaders()).filter(headers -> headers.containsKey("contentType"))
                            .map(messageHeaders -> messageHeaders.get("contentType")).map(this::typeToBinding)
                            .orElse("devNull");
                }
    
                private String typeToBinding(Object contentType) {
                    if (contentType == null) {
                        return "devNull";
                    }
                    String contentTypeAsString = null;
                    String messageType = null;
                    if (contentType instanceof byte[]) {
                        contentTypeAsString = new String((byte[]) contentType);
                    } else if (contentType instanceof String) {
                        contentTypeAsString = contentType.toString();
                    }
                    else if (contentType.getClass().isAssignableFrom(MimeType.class)) {
                        messageType = ((MimeType)contentType).getParameter("type");
                    }
                    else {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Header 'type' could neither be interpreted as String nor byte[] nor MimeType. Actual type: %s", contentType.getClass()));
                    }
                    if(messageType == null) {
                        try {
                            messageType = MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeType(contentTypeAsString).getParameter("type");
                            if(messageType == null) {
                                return "devNull";
                            }
                        } catch (InvalidMimeTypeException e) {
                            return "devNull";
                        }
                    }
                    return switch (messageType.toLowerCase()) {
                        case "org.example.shoppingcart.ordersubmittedevent" -> "orderSubmittedEventHandler";
                        case "org.example.order.ordercreatedevent" -> "orderCreatedEventHandler";
                        default -> "devNull";
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    }

My failed attempt to test that an OrderCreatedEvent is published when an OrderSubmittedEvent is received:
@SpringBootTest
@EnableTestBinder
public class OrderProcessingApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    private InputDestination input;

    @Autowired
    private OutputDestination output;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        input.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(new OrderSubmittedEvent(UUID.randomUUID(), UUID.randomUUID(), List.of(new LineItem("foo", 10, 1), new LineItem("bar", 20, 2))))
                .setHeader("contentType", "application/json;type=org.example.shoppingcart.OrderSubmittedEvent")
                .build());
        assertThat(output.receive().getPayload()).isNotEmpty();
    }
}

The test fails with ava.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.messaging.Message.getPayload()" because the return value of "org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.OutputDestination.receive()" is null

You are showing the result of the test demonstrating that you have not received a Message, but what was the actual exception?

Also, it appears you are creating an infinite loop, so i suspect you get some kind of recursive error. You are sending to functionRouter-out-0 which is mapped to the same destination as functionRouter-in-0, so your message keeps circling around. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Hi @OlegZhurakousky, thx for chiming in. I expected the output destination to receive the OrderCreatedEvent. The event is published when using the real Kafka Binding. The infinite loop does not occur since consuming the OrderCreatedEvent does not lead to any other publishing.

Also I wish there was a more straightforward way to only handle certain messages (based on a header value) and ignore others and also do the payload mapping based on the header value. The solution I used seemed a little too involved.

What do you mean too involved? If you want to route messages based on the header value all you need is have a spring.cloud.funuction.definitioin header pointing to the name of the function. You don't need to implement MessageRoutingCallback at all. Just read the section passed MessageRoutingCallback - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/reference/spring-cloud-function/programming-model.html#function-routing-and-filtering

How practical is this? The function name should be an implementation detail that the producer should not care about. The producer does not even know its consumers. Concerning my testing problem would you agree with my expectation?

Ideally I could configure Spring Cloud Stream to tell it that for a certain destination I want to handle messages based on a header value A with a function/consumer B even without writing any code, just plain configuration. The more general feature request would be - make consuming different types of messages easier when they share the same destination.


If you read the same document, you will see there is a SpEL expression you can use which makes it completely dynamic without user knowing it.  2. It is very practical if the name of the function come from other applications in implementations where there are well known and established functions. We can do this all day, but I still don't understand what exactly you are trying to accomplish. . . what is your use case?


Thanks for staying with me  my use case is like I said -  handling certain types of messages in a topic while ignoring others, based on a header value. Additionally the handling function also produces to the same topic and another consumer of the same app handles the message as to not really on a transactional outbox pattern. Maybe Spring Cloud Stream is not the right choice for this? Maybe it's more suited to the FaaS type of architecture where you only use one function per deployment?
